# JTextArea.copy() clipboard cleared when program exits

Tags: java, clipboard

I have a JDialog with a JTextArea component. This dialog shows the user what arguments to use when running the program to have it run the mode they just set up. I have a button on the dialog to copy the arguments to clipboard. This uses the copy() method on the JTextArea object.

This works perfectly and the clipboard contains the correct text up until the program is closed. Then the clipboard is lost. Is there anyway to have it retain this after the program is quit? The normal operation would be to then quit the program and start it again with the arguments.

This might sound strange but the idea is the user would setup an environment with the GUI and then run it with the arguments in a cron or similar.

Comment: Even if you do get this to work, isn't it subject to the user not putting something on the clipboard after your program does but before your program uses it?  Which would mean the user could accidentally screw up your program.

Comment: hi @Android did you find any solution for your problem?

Answer (score 1):

I just learned, that there are two clipboards in Java, a local one and a system one. Would explain something, if you just took the local clipboard.

[Here's an example](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=82) that uses the system clipboard. Hope it solves your issue!

Comment: This works but still have the same problem when the program closes.

Comment: Very, very strange - can you double-check if you do not accidently copy some empty or other objects to the clipboard just before closing the app, iaw, accidentally overwriting the content?

Comment: I just copy pasted and ran the program on that link. The clipboard is cleared when the program exits. Added a thread.sleep to the last line and the text was on the clipboard up until it ended.

Answer (score 1):

Works fine for me when I use Ctrl+C to copy the contents of the text component. So try using the supplied Action (which is what Ctrl+C uses) to do the copy instead of the copy() method:

```
JButton button = new JButton(DefaultEditorKit.CopyAction());
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Robot to simulate Ctrl + c

```
 Robot robot = new Robot();
 robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
 robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_C);
 robot.keyRelease( KeyEvent.VK_C );
 robot.keyRelease( KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL );
```

This will definitely stays in the clipboard even after you close your program.

Or you can try

```
StringSelection ss = new StringSelection("your text for clipboard");
Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard().setContents(ss, null);
```

which works for me in Windows 7.

Comment: Interesting, in Linux the clipboard is lost upon program termination. Even a manual CTRL-C is lost.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using the [Preferences API](http://www.j2ee.me/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/prefs/Preferences.html) for this instead.

Comment: The argument is a path to a configuration file that it should load. It is likely that the user would set up a lot of these so I can't just have a default file that is always loaded at startup.

Comment: but you can only have one of them in the clipboard at a time right?  so when they change it via your button you save it to the clipboard and then the program uses that value.  What I am suggesting is the same thing - press the button and save it via Preferences, then when the program looks for it rather than look in the clipboard it uses the Preferences to grab it.  Same data, same flow, jsut look in a different place.

Answer (score 0):

For me, this is just enough:

```
JButton buttonCopy = new JButton(new DefaultEditorKit.CopyAction());
buttonCopy.setText("copy");
```